# What does setParent of InputMap do in Java?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to use Java Swing Keybind API as it's the recommended way to listen for key presses in Java. The InputMap class has a setParent() method. The documentation says that it'll look for keybinds in the parent map if it's not registered in the InputMap. But in practice, the only InputMap I ever use is the default InputMap in every component. So how exactly do I use the parent-child structure of InputMap and when should I use it?

Comment: Have you read [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)? Here is a quote: _Each `JComponent` has one action map and three input maps._

Comment: All components of a given class (JButton, JTable, etc) share the same parent InputMap so all instances have the same bindings. However you could customize the InputMap for a given instance of the component. It nothing you really need to worry about. At least I've never have.